# Error code 43, is my mouse dead or is my usb driver installation corrupted?

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, mouse

My old mouse stopped working about an hour ago. I am on a Sony Vaio with Windows 7. I found an error code 43 in the USB panel. I googled it and found [instructions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725873(v=ws.10).aspx) to try to restore the connection. Unfortunately, it did not solve the issue.

I then tried to plug an external IOmega drive on that USB port and it worked well. My first conclusion is that my mouse was simply dead.

Then, I tried using another mouse, which I know works, on that USB port (and others too). I can see the red laser underneath it, but it does not move the pointer.

When I scan for new hardware from the Device Manager, I get the Driver Software Installation window, and after one minute, it says: 'No driver found' for Base System Device.

So is my mouse dead or is there a driver installation corruption? Or both? What else can I try to solve my issue? Thanks.

Comment: Hard to say. Are you able to test the mouse on a different machine? That would be the best test.

Comment: Not for now, but I will as soon as I can.

Comment: Try a System Restore back to a point before it stopped working.  Does it work?  Try another OS (like a Linux LiveCD), does it work in there?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, about 2 hours after I asked this question here, Windows somehow managed to re-install the problematic USB driver. It did it by itself. So, I plugged my mouse and there it was working again...

But, I noticed my camera was not working/detected anymore. I read somewhere on the net that I should shutdown my PC completely and restart windows. I shutdown my PC (not the usual sleep mode) for the whole night and restarted it in the morning. My camera was working again.

Apparently, the restart facilitated the re-initialization of drivers.